# Modifying method parameters

Tags: dafny

Is it possible to annotate Dafny method parameters as mutable, without them being objects?

My goal is to be able to verify

```
method testMethod(a:int, b:int) returns (res :int) {
  res :=0;
  a := (a - b);
  assert a < (a-b);
}
```

Ignoring the fact this is obviously an absurd assertion, Dafny complains about the LHS not being a mutable variable, while I'd like to avoid introducing temporary variables.

Answer (score 2):

All in-parameters in Dafny are immutable (including in-parameters of reference types, though with an appropriate `modifies` clause a method can make modifications in the heap by dereferencing such a parameter). So, you need to use a local variable to store the expression `a - b` in your example. For example:

```
method testMethod(a:int, b:int) returns (res:int) {
  res := 0;
  var myLocalA := a - b;
  assert myLocalA < myLocalA - b;
}
```

If you are bothered by having to introduce a new name for the local variable, Dafny actually allows you to give a local variable the same name as an in-parameter. If you find that to be in your style, you can write:

```
method testMethod(a:int, b:int) returns (res:int) {
  res := 0;
  var a := a - b;
  assert a < a - b;
}
```

Note that the right-hand side of the assignment to the local variable `a` mentions the in-parameter `a` (because the local variable `a` is not quite yet in scope at that time).

If you do this a lot, you can also start your method off with a statement

```
var a := a;
```

This looks ridiculous and may be confusing until you realize what's going on, namely that this statement introduces a local variable `a` and assigns its initial value the value of the in-parameter `a`.

The reason for not automatically allowing in-parameters to be used as local variables (which is allowed by many other languages, including C and Java) is that, in my experience, some people then get confused about the meaning of in-parameters in postconditions. An in-parameter mentioned in a postcondition refers to the value of the in-parameter passed in by the caller, and this is made clear by making in-parameters immutable inside the method body.

Rustan